# Как заставить SeekBar отображаться правильно?

Tags: java, android

Пишу простенькое приложение для плавного изменения уровня подсветки экрана(фактически аналог того, что есть в настройках). SeekBar на экране Api 22 отображается странно: бегунок расположен отдельно,

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот исходники:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
android:id="@+id/textView"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="10dp"
android:layout_weight="5"
android:textSize="40sp"
android:text="Яркость:" />

<SeekBar
android:id="@+id/seekBar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="100dp"
android:layout_weight="5"
android:min="15"
android:max="200"
android:progress="3"
/>
</LinearLayout>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
private TextView textView;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

final SeekBar seekBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(this);
textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
textView.setText("Яркость: " + 
Settings.System.getString(this.getContentResolver(),"screen_brightness"));


seekBar.setProgress(Integer.parseInt(Settings.System.getString(
this.getContentResolver(),"screen_brightness")));
}

@Override
public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean 
fromUser) {

}

@Override
public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

}

@Override
public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
android.provider.Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),
android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 
seekBar.getProgress());

    textView.setText(String.valueOf(seekBar.getProgress()));
    }
    }
```

Comment: попробуйте в seekbar установить высоту wrapcontent

Comment: Те же яйца, только в профиль.

Comment: А зачем вам weight ? Вы хотите чтобы ваш бар был посередине экрана ?

Comment: можно еще так попробовать - android:splitTrack="false"

Comment: Разобрался. Просто заменил LinearLayout на ConstraintLayout.